# Increase size of boxplot names in R

Tags: r, formatting, boxplot

I'm having issues in locating an answer for this, as I don't want to increase the size of the x-axis label, but the names attribute of my boxplot.

I am generating a 1x3 subplot, with 3 boxes shown within each boxplot.

```
data1 = c(d1, d3, d3)
data2 = c(e1, e2, e3)
data3 = c(f1, f2, f3)
lbls = c("Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3")
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
boxplot(data1, names=lbls, ylab="Components", main="First Plot", ylim=c(0,1500))
boxplot(data2, names=lbls, ylab="Components", main="Second Plot", ylim=c(0,1500))
boxplot(data3, names=lbls, ylab="Components", main="Third Plot", ylim=c(0,1500))
```

I have tried playing around with things like `par(cex.lab=1.5)`, `boxplot(..., label.cex=1.5)`, and so on, but nothing actually increases the size of the names field, only the label axes.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using the `par()` command with the appropriate command will allow you to resize it.

Try using one of the two following commands with varying sizes and it should work out for you.

```
par(cex.lab=1.5) # is for y-axis

par(cex.axis=1.5) # is for x-axis
```

Comment: Just adding in case someone else finds this question from the same place I did. I came here to find the `cex.names` argument, which corresponds to the `names.arg` labels.

Comment: Good answer. You can also use `par(cex.main=#)` to resize the main title.